# ArrayPlot gives wrong plot legend, how to fix?

Tags: plotting, bugs, legending

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and fixed in 11.2.0.0**

---

My minimal working example is the code

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

The plot legend shows up as a bar legend, but the colors in the legend are inconsistent with what is shown in the array plot.

Here is the plot:

[image]

but here is the the plot legend that is generated along with it.

[image]

You can see white and black seem to be reversed from what they should be. Here as some related questions: [Bar legend coloring doesn't correspond to array plot coloring in the expected way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104989/7182), and [MatrixPlot provides wildly inaccurate PlotLegend?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63349/7182)

My question is: Why is *Mathematica* doing this, and how can I fix it? (I am running version 10.4.1.0.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a bug.  Please report it to Wolfram Support.

A simple workaround is to specify your own colour function.

```
ArrayPlot[{{1, 0.1, 0}, {0.1, 0, 0}}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> (GrayLevel[1 - #] &)]
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, I reported it. I guess I will maybe put an update in the question if anything happens.

Comment: @NowIGetToLearnWhatAHeadIs Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Automatic Legends for `ArrayPlot` still need some work in v-13.0.0

[image]

[image]